# Use distinct and sort together using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use distinct and sort together in my NodeJS code.

```
var specialityInfo = docUser.find(
        { 'primarySpeciality': regex }
  ).sort({"updated_at":-1}).distinct('primarySpeciality').sort({"created_at" : -1}).sort({visits: -1}).limit(5);
```

please help me!!!!

Comment: Please update with sample input data/JSON and expected output/JSON. Since the question is tagged in MongoDB as well, is it ok to give the solution in MongoDB query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't.

The [cursor distinct](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-distinct) function is a unique `mongoose` feature, they also specifically specify on their [sort cursor](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-distinct) this:

> Cannot be used with distinct()

Thus the solution you want does not exist as this behaviour is intended. The next best thing you can do is to use this pipeline:

```
var specialityInfo = docUser.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {'primarySpeciality': regex}
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            updated_at: -1,
            created_at: -1,
            visits: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            primaries: {$addToSet: "$primarySpeciality"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            primaries: {
                $slice: ["$primaries", 5]
            }
        }
    }
])
```